# Is natural to use the phrasal verb "check with" in the sense of "consult"?

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

Is it natural to use *check with* in the following sentence?

> If you don't know the meaning of words, **check with** dictionaries to find out.

Comment: Best check something **with** somebody; check something **in** a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is natural, at least in U.S. English. It is, however, informal; some may say very informal.

"Consult" has an implication of more than brief interaction and does not imply "need to gain consent." "Check with" implies something almost perfunctory in terms of time, but frequently implies "need to gain assent."

> Yes, Bobby may stay for dinner if he checks with his parents

is a natural thing for a parent to say to a child about whether the child's friend may stay for dinner. It would be odd to say

> Yes, Bobby may stay for dinner if he consults his parents.

Whereas

> I'll first consult with my sister about my parents' long-term care

would be a natural thing to say if you were the legal guardian of your parents but respected your sister's judgment. It would be potentially misleading and perhaps sound a bit flippant to say

> I'll first check with my sister about my parents' long-term care

if you were the legal guardian of your parents but respected your sister's judgment.

In short, the two verbs have similar but not always identical meanings and differ in tone.